# Picking the first group of regex map as a new column

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe 'df', with many column, I am trying to extract the ZIP code from the column called "ADDRESS" and create a new columns called "ZIP" and "ZIP1"

Now I am accounting for two possibility (may expand to more later), where ZIP is a continuous six digit number(non US) and ZIP is split by a '-'

I am using the following script to do this:

```
df['ZIP'] = df['ADDRESS'].str.extract('\d\d\d\d\d\d')
df['ZIP1']= df['ADDRESS'].str.extract('\d\d\d-\d\d\d')
```

But I get the following error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 1393, in extract
    result, name = str_extract(self._data, pat, flags=flags)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 477, in str_extract
    raise ValueError("This pattern contains no groups to capture.")
ValueError: This pattern contains no groups to capture.
```

I understand that this is because the Address may have other numbers, thus regex leads to multiple matches, is there a way I have specify which group to select and insert in the new columns called 'ZIP'

---

CODE NEEDS MODIFICATION

```
import re    
a="results_item12345"
pattern=re.compile(r"(\D+)(\d+)")
x=pattern.match(a).groups()
print x[1]
```

The code if its is modified for a data frame, then thats exactly what I am looking for

P.S: Using Mac and Python 3.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks for pointing it out, no impact on the code though

Comment: Do you really need `.str` in `df['ADDRESS'].str`? because `df['ADDRESS']` seems to be the string

Comment: FYI, `\d\d\d\d\d\d` can be written as `\d{6}` and same for other `\d{3}-\d{3}`

Comment: Not sure, I am pretty new to Python, I picked this in one of the guides

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for this, no your FYI, just made the code more readable

Comment: I got the following warning: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead, it worked!

Comment: @user3875610: Please post your solution if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following the solution that worked for me, although it gave me some warning, hope this helps. Basically it does not solve the 'group' problem but so far this is the best I have

```
#******************************************************************************************#
#*                        IMPORTING THE NECESSARY LIBRARIES                               *#
#******************************************************************************************#

import pandas as pd
import re
#******************************************************************************************#
#*                         IMPORTING THE .CSV                               *#
#******************************************************************************************#

print (" \n Importing the .csv from folder \n")

df_input = pd.read_csv('/Users/one/input.csv', 
    encoding = "ISO-8859-1")


#******************************************************************************************#
#*        CREATING A REGEX TO GET THE PIN CODE FROM THE ADDRESS COLUMN                    *#
#******************************************************************************************#

# Any continous six digit number
df_input['ZIP'] = df_input['ADDRESS'].str.extract(r'(\d{6})')

# Any six digit number separated by space
df_input['ZIP1'] = df_input['ADDRESS'].str.extract(r'(\d{3}\s\d{3})')

#******************************************************************************************#
#*        EXPORTING TO THE LOCAL DRIVE                                  *#
#******************************************************************************************#
# Output
df_input.to_csv('/Users/one/output/df_mapped.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```